# Changing the position of the button

Tags: android

how do i change the position of my button
in my screen dynamically???

example:

change the x position and my y position 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally you set button positions in the layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have two options:

1. Code your UI completely using Java (Full flexibility)
2. Use layout parameter to set the layout to position (Limited settings)